# @OneToOne or @ManyToOne references an unknown entity

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

I am trying to make a relationship between 2 entities in different jar. 
This is a first entity which is in main project:

```
    @Entity(name = "StdyDtlLabelBean")
    @Table(name = "STDY_DTL_LABEL")
    public class StdyDtlLabelBean implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private StdyDtlLabelBeanPk id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = StdyDtlSubject.class)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="STUDY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName="STUDY_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name="SUBJECT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName="SUBJECT_ID")
    })
    private StdyDtlSubject subject;
//getters and setters

}
```

This one is an entity which is in library project as a jar file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STDY_DTL_SUBJECT")
public class StdyDtlSubject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2479124604L;

    public StdyDtlSubject() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private StdyDtlSubjectPK key;

//getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
public class StdyDtlSubjectPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6691432687933341920L;
    @Column(name = "STUDY_ID")
    private Integer studyId;
    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_ID")
    private String subjectId;

    public StdyDtlSubjectPK() {
    }
```

Here is the persistence unit:

```
<persistence-unit name="stdyPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/OraclePooledDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.ctasc.ctpm.jpa.StdyDtlSubject</class>
        <class>stdy.brms.beans.StdyDtlLabelBean</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

When I create an entity manager factory I gets following error:

```
@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on stdy.brms.beans.StdyDtlLabelBean.subject references an unknown entity: com.ctasc.ctpm.jpa.StdyDtlSubject
```

But if I remove a relationship annotation from StdyDtlLabelBean entity and create named queries on StdyDtlSubject entity. Those named queries work fine. Also, if I copy StdyDtlSubject class to my main project, it works fine. I gets this error only if I put relationship between them.

I've tried adding

```
<jar-file>ctpm.jar</jar-file>
<jar-file>lib/ctpm.jar</jar-file>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ctasc.ctpm.jpa" />
```

None of them helped me to solve this. Could you please suggest something to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the jar which you want to relate to has a persisence.xml in it's META-INF with all entities in the jar enlisted.

Comment: Thank you @hragheb! I have only one persistence.xml in my main project. And I declared all the entities in that persistence.xml either main and 2nd project which was added as a library jar. There is no persistence.xml in my 2nd project . Do I really have to have entities in each project? There is no problem to get those entities and read the data. But when I try to put some relationship between entities in 2 different project, I get that unknown entity error